# Why does my React Web App look way different on some mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

This is my first question ever, so I apologize for any inconveniences in advance :)

I've been coding a static website in React using styled-components, and everything looks the way it should EXCEPT for on certain mobile devices. For some reason, almost all divs layers on top of each other, and buttons do not display properly - the worst bit is, that there seems to be no consistency between the broken styling. It works for some (iPhone XS for example) and it doesn't work for others (iPhone 11) - and I have no idea why.

Here are some pictures of how it looks on some mobile devices:

Intended look of first section:
[image: Intended look of first section]

Intended look of first section:
[image: Intended look of third section]

And here are some pictures of how broken it looks on my iPhone 11 for example:

Weird look of first section (the button is collapsed):
[image: Weird look of first section (the button is collapsed)]

Complete mess - all sections collapsed on top of each other:
[image: Complete mess - all sections collapsed on top of each other]

I've tried all the things I could think of:

- I've tried using pure css instead of styled-components
- I'm using    Gatsby so I've also tried reinstalling gatsby and
  gatsby-cli and    afterwards making a clean project
- I've tried deploying a clean react    app (no gatsby) with just the
  code for the first section (still, the    button looks weird)
- I've tried changing the CSS for the button (just    for testing out
  where the errors are from before refactoring       everything -
  still,    no effect)
- I've tried deploying through Vercel    (instead of Netlify)
- I've used https://autoprefixer.github.io to    make sure that all my
  code CSS was supported on different browsers.

  None of these attempts changed anything.

I have no clue where to go now. Any Ideas?

For reference, here is the Button component - did I mess something up? (sorry, it's really ugly):

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

export default function Button({ content }) {
  return (
    <Container>
      <B href="#contactSection">{content}</B>
    </Container>
  );
}

const Container = styled.div`
  margin-top: 60px;

  width: 240px;
  height: 55px;

  background-color: rgb(35, 190, 115);
  border-radius: 30px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;

  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;

  -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;

  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
  -o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);

  &:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }

  @media (max-width: 960px) {
    -ms-flex-item-align: center;
    -ms-grid-row-align: center;
    align-self: center;
  }
`;

const B = styled.a`
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
`;
```

Here is a link to the GitHub repo: https://github.com/ErikBachRyhl/worklay-website

This is a pretty chaotic post, but it is my last resort - any suggestions are extremely welcome, I'll take all the help I can get.
Best regards and thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code looks fine to me... you sure you are testing the same browsers on those mobile devices? if the device is the same, and its OS version is the same, and the browser is the same, it wouldn't make sense that css looks different

Comment: Pretty sure this is caused by something quite unrelated to your code, like aggressively cached assets or something like that, although Gatsby should have taken care of that.

Comment: Hard to spot the problem with this, can you publish your code on GitHub Page so we can see the whole thing, it seems not only the button is the problem.

Comment: @IWI I've tried both safari and the chrome app on my iPhone 11, and the CSS messed up in both cases. On some iPhones it works perfectly fine on safari... But I can't figure out why there would be such a huge different between the way the CSS loads from iPhone XS to iPhone 11 for example.

Comment: @oligofren Do you have any takes on a possible solution?

Comment: @CoPham I totally agree, I think its more than just the button. I've just been using it as a benchmark to test the CSS because constantly rewriting everything would be a lot. Here is a link to the code on Github: https://github.com/ErikBachRyhl/worklay-website (You will see that the first section uses .css-files instead of styled-components. This didn't work, unfortunately)

Comment: Try to change your firstContainer height to min-height, delete the height: 100% in the body, font-weight of your button to 600, try different font to see if it better or not.

Comment: @CoPham It worked! This fixed it for the button. I did some more testing with the difference between height and min-height, and I also stopped using "flex: 1 1 0" and replaced it with "width: 50%" for both my left and right sides in each section. Apparently, this was the problem (or at least it fixed it ;))

I am very new to Stack Overflow; how do I mark your comment as the answer to give you credit? Maybe you could make an answer with the information I've gathered as well, so that it might be helpful for others? Then I will be able to mark it correct. 

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Glad I could help, I made an answer so I may help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, this problem solved by changing some CSS:

- Changed the height to min-height in firstContainer class.
- Remove the height: 100% in the body.
- Changed font-weight from 700 to 600.
- Replace height, width to min-height, min-width depends on the requirements.
- Replace flex: 1 1 0 to width: 50% in children.